# Django: Check if Today in Range of Datetime Object

Tags: python, django, datetime, middleware, django-middleware

(Django 1.10 , Python 2.7)

I have a year model:

```
class Year(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    election_nomination_start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    election_nomination_end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to make a Middleware -which I've never done before- to check if `datetime.today` or `datetime.now` is within the range of dates between `election_nomination_start_datetime` and `election_nomination_end_datetime` of any of the Year objects; and accordingly certain pages' accessibility will differ.

I have no idea how to execute this, so any help is much appreciated.
Also, if an example could be given for using middlewares the way I've described above (limiting access to URLs etc), that would be very beneficial for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that a middleware is the correct approach here? If certain views should only be accessible at certain times, wouldn't it be better to check that in the view?

Comment: like @Alasdair said, why do need middleware? I've done something similar before using querysets objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Year(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    election_nomination_start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    election_nomination_end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = YearQuerySet().as_manager()


class YearQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def occurring_in_day(self, year, month, day):
        try:
            picked_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return self.none()

        return self.filter(
            election_nomination_start_datetime__lte=picked_date,
            election_nomination_end_datetime__gte=picked_date,
        )

    def occurring_now(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        return self.filter(
            election_nomination_start_datetime__lte=now,
            election_nomination_end_datetime__gte=now,
        )
```

Then you can do something like

`Year.objects.occurring_now()` to get instances occurring now

and to get instance occurring today, do

```
today = datetime.today()
day = today.day
month = today.month
year = today.year
Year.objects. occurring_in_day(year, month, day)
```